# Upload file asynchronously using dynamically added input file control

Tags: jquery, file, asynchronous, upload, facebox

Any suggestions how I would save a file to the server asynchronously, using a dynamically added (by jQuery) input file control (non-server control)?

I can't use server controls as the control will be inside a jquery facebox (does not play nice with server controls, i.e. duplicate id's, etc)

Comment: http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Answer (score 0):

1. Google for jquery Uploadify plugin.
2. You will need a controller on server side which accept the request and save file to ther server.

Comment: Would prefer a control that has the same look and feel as the input file control. Also, after I upload the file to the server, I then process it into a database and upload it to sharepoint. With the file input control I can make it look like it's one process, with uploadify, it will be two processes.